# jquery fancybox2 - loading a div using fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a form as the following :

```
<div id='popUpForm' style="display:none;z-index: 999999;">
some content
</div>
```

and a `<div id='overlayFormWrapper'></div>`

I would like to trigger that popUpForm to popup as a fancybox. How do I achieve it ? I need the content of that div to load inside the fancybox2.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an anchor pointing to that form with a specific `class` or `ID` like

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#popUpForm">open form in fancybox</a>
```

Then you need to bind that selector (`class="fancybox"`) to fancybox ... with this custom script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   width: 480, // or whatever
   height: 320,
   autoSize : false
 }); // fancybox
}); // ready
</script>
```

Optionally your form may have already some dimensions set through CSS so in that case you don't need to set `width` nor `height` within fancybox and `autoSize`  should be set to `true`.

PS. I didn't understand what is the role of `<div id='overlayFormWrapper'></div>`

**UPDATE**:
To launch the form (in fancybox) after an event, you could create a *function* :

```
function fancyForm(){
 $.fancybox({
   href     : "#popUpForm",
   autoSize : true,
   fitToView: false
 });
}
```

Then just call that *function* after your event. Since your `form` has already a size, `autoSize` will set the fancybox size according to those dimensions.

Comment: the form is called on certain event and not by clicking a link. How do I open it in that way ? my form already has a certain size, how do I adjust my fancybox2 to be at this size? thx

Comment: the popupform does get into the fancybox div but it wont autosize. the popupform div is bigger in size than the fancybox, how do I fix it?

Comment: @Alon you said the `popUpForm` has dimensions so this is either through css or inline `style="width: 320px; height: 600px;"` for instance, is that correct? ... or does the form size change dynamically?